# XSLT finding last parent's preceding sibling with non zero value

Tags: xslt, siblings

XML:

```
   <h>
    <rl>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
    </rl>
    <rl>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c>.01</c>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
    </rl>
    <rl>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
    </rl>
    <rl>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c/>
      <c>.01</c>
      <c>.01</c>
      <c>.01</c>
      <c>.01</c>
    </rl>
</h>
```

The problem I faced is:

I need to select a value from 4th `<c>` element of every `<rl>` element with special conditions: 
Let's say, that `rl[3]/c[4]` is my current node. I need to find last parent's sibling with non zero value in `c[4]` and check it's value (in this case it would be `rl[2]/c[4]` which is 0.01).

Any ideas are appreciated.

/EDIT
Maybe I wasn't clear enough:
I never know in which `rl` element I have this non-zero value, so the formula must be artful enough to find it. In this case, non zero value is inside the second `rl` element but it may be in 1st or 3rd and if I will be matching 4th, 5th and so on `rl` element, it needs to find a value from non empty `rl` element at every step.

Answer (score 0):

If your current node is `rl[3]/c[4]` and you want to get `<c>.01</c>` use XPATH `rl[3]/c[4]/parent::rl/preceding-sibling::rl[1]/c[4]`.

Comment: This seems not to fulfill the request: "_I need to find last parent's sibling with non zero value in c[4]_" Even if I'm not sure what the "last parent" should be in this context.

Comment: Yup, exactly. Regarding the "last parent" part: it's not last parent, it's last parent's sibling. So, if i'm in `rl[3]/c[4]` my parent is `rl[3]` and my last parent's sibling with a value is `rl[2]`

Comment: But only if  rl[2] has a c[4] with some text?

Answer (score 0):

For your example xml a key base solution will do
Add a key for c "potion in r1:

```
<xsl:key name="kCpos" match="rl/c" use="count(preceding-sibling::c)+1"/>
```

Than you can easily select all c at a certain potion (e.g 4) and condition (has text):

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('kCpos', 4)[text()]"/>
```

To get the `rl` for this condition:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('kCpos', 4)[text()]/.." />
```

The **4** can be relapsed  by something like `count(preceding-sibling::c)+1`

Answer (score -1):

Ok,
It took me some time to solve this, but here it is:

`<xsl:template match="c">`
`<xsl:variable name="prev-non-zero-value">`
`<xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::rl[child::c[position()='4']!=''][position()='1']/c[position()='4']"/>`
`</xsl:variable>`
`</xsl:template>`

To explain it:
I'm matching `c` element and creating `prev-non-zero-value` variable with a value:
1. `../preceding-sibling::rl` - selecting `c`'s parent preceding sibling:  (`rl`)
2. `[child::c[position()='4']` - matching only `rl` elements which has 4th child `c` element with value different from ''
3. `[position()='1']` choosing first matched `rl` element from the list (as preceding counts elements "up")
4. `/c[position()='4']` - selecting 4th child `c` element of given `rl` element
5. Profit

This is really complicated, so if you have any other ideas how to solve this, I'm really open for any suggestions ;)